# Problem linking Boost.Filesystem statically to a shared library

Tags: c++, boost, static-linking, boost-filesystem, undefined-symbol

I'm building a shared library with `GCC 4.5.2` and `Boost 1.46.1` (compiled with `--build-type=complete`) and this is a command from Makefile which does the linkage part:

```
$(CXX) -static -lboost_filesystem -fpic -shared $^ -o $@
```

Everything compiles fine but I get the following error when it gets loaded by application:

```
plugins/crashdetect.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost11filesystem34path21wchar_t_codecvt_facetEv
```

`ldd`outputs:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x002f8000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00bf5000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0032d000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00506000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x006f6000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00110000)
```

I beleive this means that it linked Boost statically.

This is what `nm crashdetect.so -u | grep boost` says:

```
 U _ZN5boost11filesystem34path21wchar_t_codecvt_facetEv
 U _ZN5boost11filesystem36detail13dir_itr_closeERPvS3_
 U _ZN5boost11filesystem36detail28directory_iterator_constructERNS0_18directory_iteratorERKNS0_4pathEPNS_6system10error_codeE
 U _ZN5boost11filesystem36detail28directory_iterator_incrementERNS0_18directory_iteratorEPNS_6system10error_codeE
 U _ZN5boost11filesystem36detail6statusERKNS0_4pathEPNS_6system10error_codeE
 U _ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv
 U _ZN5boost6system16generic_categoryEv
 U _ZNK5boost11filesystem315directory_entry12m_get_statusEPNS_6system10error_codeE
```

So I think since that symbol goes first in this list then most likely there's nothing special about it.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**
So is this impossible or what?

Comment: Why are you statically linking libraries into a shared library? Is that even a supported mode of operation?

Comment: @bdonlan: Well, I'm not an expert in Linux but on Windows I was able to statically link libraies to DLLs

Comment: Try to change arguments order: `$(CXX) -fpic -shared $^ -o $@ -static -lboost_filesystem`

Comment: @php-coder: If I change the order like you said then `libboost_filesystem.so.1.46.1` and `libboost_system.so.1.46.1` appear in dependencies

Comment: static linking is very unusual on Linux, and static linking in a solib is even more rare - doing something like that can break things due to symbol collisions between different ABI-compatible versions of the library. So don't do that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that:

1. Your use of -static and -shared is not the right way. The only more-or-less reliable way   to control linking would be:

   -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_filesystem -Wl,-Bshared

   at the end of the command line.
2. You fail to link to boost_system.
3. The failure happens because you seem to actually link to the static version of boost_filesystem. However, because it's specified on the command line before any object files, no symbol is actually pulled from it, and every reference to boost.filesystem functions remains undefined. And yes, the linker complains on the first undefined symbol.